# Stub/mock process.platform sinon

Tags: node.js, mocking, sinon, stub

I am working with `process.platform` and want to stub that string value to fake different OSes.

(this object is generated out of my reach, and I need to test against  different values it can take on)

### Is it possible to stub/fake this value?

I have tried the following without any luck:

```
stub = sinon.stub(process, "platform").returns("something")
```

I get the error `TypeError: Attempted to wrap string property platform as function`

The same thing happens if I try to use a mock like this:

```
mock = sinon.mock(process);
mock.expects("platform").returns("something");
```

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Anyone please correct me if I'm off base here. I normally use stubs to create fake functions/methods that are used by the function/method being tested in order to create a predictable scenario for the function/method being tested. I've never tested the returned value of a stubbed method, since (assuming that I'm forcing my stub method to return a value) I know what that value will be already. It makes even less sense to assign a value to an object property just to turn around and test it.  Maybe I misunderstood your question. If so, please elaborate some more.

Comment: So, maybe there is too little context here. What I am doing is making a cross-platform npm module which must act differently on different OS-es, thus I must stub/fake which operating system I am on. I have to stub `process.platform`, which I believe I can't change by simply overwriting it.

Comment: Sure you can. I'll post it as my answer.

Comment: @Cort3z your example code should reference `process.platform` instead of `global.generated_object`. Always show real code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't need Sinon to accomplish what you need. Although the `process.platform` process is not `writable`, it is `configurable`. So, you can temporarily redefine it and simply restore it when you're done testing.

Here's how I would do it:

```
var assert = require('assert');

describe('changing process.platform', function() {
  before(function() {
    // save original process.platform
    this.originalPlatform = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(process, 'platform');

    // redefine process.platform
    Object.defineProperty(process, 'platform', {
      value: 'any-platform'
    });
  });

  after(function() {
    // restore original process.platfork
    Object.defineProperty(process, 'platform', this.originalPlatform);
  });

  it('should have any-platform', function() {
    assert.equal(process.platform, 'any-platform');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

sinon's stub supports a "value" function to set the new value for a stub now:

```
sinon.stub(process, 'platform').value('ANOTHER_OS');
...
sinon.restore() // when you finish the mocking
```

For details please check from https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/